# Logic app to pause and start Azure Analysis Services

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-analysis-services

To my knowledge, there is no way to set up simple Logic apps for the purpose of starting and pausing Azure Analysis Services. In the Azure portal, the task is accomplished by one click of a button. In contrast, for Azure VM, automating start/stop is readily available with the Azure VM connector and corresponding actions. How come Microsoft have not made it just as easy to start/pause AAS??

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's just venting, not asking for a solution to a problem.

Comment: There may not be a dedicated action but there are REST API’s … https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/analysisservices/servers/suspend